# i have a Theoretical questin about saving and sending message data (video, audio) to firebase users

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase-realtime-database

i wanna know how the user can send data to other users, sending text message is so easy also sending photos and videos from photo library, and my question is about the recorded Messages and Videos like snapshot, the idea is when the user finish record a video snapchat app save it and play it right away, also if I record a sound I know how to save it but if i want to send this saved data
do i need to Upload this data to the firebase then send it to the user ?
and if i save it on database should I delete it from my device ?
do I even need to save it on my device before i send it to the user to play it right away ? 
how this process can work ? 
im new to programming also to this web site so please Excuse me if there is anything wrong or unclear about my question

Comment: Please divide your problems into seperate questions

Comment: it's not a problem it's Theoretical question